# Do each participant´s data points from two measurement correlate within participant - how to analyze?

Tags: correlation, biostatistics

Sorry for perhaps a little confusing title. I am lost with a relatively simple question. I measured each participant's heart rate in different parts of the experiment as well as asked each participant at the same parts of the experiment how stressed they are (likert from 0-10). Now what I would like to know is that do these data points within each participant correlate. The question regarding the graph is if the participant reports that from the first measurement point to the second (and to the third, fourth and so on) experienced stress increases/decreases, does the heart rate increase/decrease too? Or is it even correlation that should focus here? What would be the best way to analyze this? From the graph, we can see that for some participants the lines are following approximately the same pattern.
[image]

The blue line = heart rate; The red line = experienced stress. Stress is divided by 10, so it better fits in the graph

Comment: It looks like a good idea might be to fit a linear mixed-effects model, with heart rate as the response variable, stress as the independent variable, and participant as a random intercept.

Comment: I forgot to say, you will probably need to add the time of the measurement as an independent variable too.

Comment: Thanks, @Adrià Luz. That I was thinking a bit too. Should I then write the formula using a colon between the independent variables?  Like this: `model <- lmer(heart_rate ~ expStress : event + (1|id), data=data`. This, however, makes me a bit confused about what I have as an intercept now. The first coefficient is "Experienced_stress : first_time_point_of_measurement".

Comment: I would do `model <- lmer(heart_rate ~ expStress*event + (1|id), data=data)` instead.

Comment: @Adrià Luz Hence, including all the main effects in the model as well. Yeah, that could make sense. I take a look into that. Thank you:)!

Comment: What's the label on the x axis? Is it a time-like variable which would suggest that observations are serially correlated? Then a mixed model might not be the best choice since `(1|id)` implies that any two pairs of observations by the same subject are equally correlated -- the order doesn't matter.

Comment: Take a look for example at [Covariance structures with glmmTMB](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/covstruct.html) though of course [glmmTMB](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/index.html) package is not the only R package that can handle complex correlation structures.